# how to change the url rediction of the woocommerce login page of the flatsome theme for my own in wordpress?

Tags: customization, login

the objective is to change the login page of my site.
I use the flatsome template.
In my functions.php file in the flatsome-child folder I created a redirection function

```
<?php
   // Add custom Theme Functions here
   function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {
          if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() ||
            is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) ) {
                 wp_redirect(home_url('/log-in'));
                 exit();
           }
    }
    add_action('template_redirect','wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
```

And when calling this function in the element-account.php file to customize the . I am always redirected to the home page.account login link.

```
   <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('template_redirect')); ?>"
         class="nav-top-link nav-top-not-logged-in <?php if($icon_style && 
         $icon_style !== 'image') echo get_flatsome_icon_class($icon_style, 
         'small'); ?>"
       <?php if( get_theme_mod('account_login_style','lightbox') == 
     'lightbox' && !is_checkout() && !is_account_page() ) echo 'data-open="#login-form-popup"'; ?>
     >
    <?php if(get_theme_mod('header_account_title', 1)) { ?>
        <span>
    <?php _e('Login', 'woocommerce'); ?>
    <?php if(get_theme_mod('header_account_register')){
    echo ' / '.__('Register', 'woocommerce');} ?>
  </span>
```

Comment: if your login URL is `/log-in` and you want to change it, just find every instance of `/log-in` and change it to what you want it to be? Or have I misunderstood? Keep in mind 3rd party theme dev support is off topic here, you cannot ask for help with a 3rd party theme here. ***You need to contact Flatsome theme support***

Comment: Okay! Sorry! I get it. But it's my own function I created to apply the redirection to the log-in page when you click on the login button, but, but it always sends me back to the home page.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/` in `home_url`?